# Neo.TransientError.Database.DatabaseUnavailable | Database 'graph.db' is unavailable

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import the **Hetionet** into the Neo4j and I follow the guidiance below:
https://github.com/hetio/hetionet/tree/master/hetnet/neo4j

While using the command

> curl --insecure --location https://github.com/hetio/hetionet/raw/master/hetnet/neo4j/hetionet-v1.0.db.tar.bz2 | tar --extract --bzip2

The error “***curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination***” has been thrown.

Therefore I just downloaded the file directly and moved to the directory ".Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-0d0d3324-d1a6-4d3e-b82c-0c4451a8c880\data\databases"

After I started the database, It showed that this database is currently offline. When I trying to do some operations to it, the error "**Neo.TransientError.Database.DatabaseUnavailable**" has been shown.

Some valuable informations in the log file debug.log are as below:

1. 2022-07-19 23:11:53.896+0000 ERROR [c.n.d.DbmsReconciler] Encountered error when attempting to reconcile database graph.db (request by SystemGraph:1) to state 'online', database remains in state 'offline'
   org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementException: Unable to start database `DatabaseId{7a8c6b65[graph.db]}`
2. Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database@3da82075' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unknown store version 'v0.A.7'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the dump you are trying to import is pretty old. From the readme

> The database has been migrated to the Neo4j 3.0.1 Community Edition.

If you use a current 4.4 version of the database, the only thing you can do is to cascade through multiple versions and upgrade the store.
I am not yet sure if you really need each minor version to work properly.
Maybe it's already enough to go from 3.0 to 3.5 and follow this guide https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/migration/migrate-to-4.0/migrate-single-instance/
Otherwise starting 3.1-3.5 with `allow_upgrade=true` on the stores is the only option I see. There are Docker images available at
https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j/ also for those older, unsupported versions.

Edit: You should be able to start/upgrade it with 3.3 and then again with 3.5 and then run a 4.4 neo4j-admin copy